# Pivot in Pivot Columns in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I am new to `SQL` and learning writing Quires. Help me. thanks in Advance.

Actually I am geeting the following Resultant table by using this `query`

```
select * from 
(select case Temp 
           when '0' then 'Temperature' 
           when '1' then 'PULSE RATE/MIN'
           when '2' then 'RESPIRATION/MIN' 
           when '3' then 'BLOOD PRESSURE' 
           when '4' then 'URINE' 
        end as Temp,
        Value, 
        convert(nvarchar(15),Date,103) Date,
       concat(case Time 
                 when '0' then '2' 
                 when '1' then '6' 
                 when '2' then '10' 
              end,' ',
              case AMPM 
                 when '0' then 'AM' 
                 when '1' then 'PM' 
              end)[Tim]
from HMS_Chart_Clinical
where status = '0' and IPNO='21460') as s
pivot(max(Value) for [date] in ([07/11/2016],[08/11/2016])) as datapivot
pivot(max(Tim) for [Tim] in ([2 AM],[6 AM],[10 AM],[2 PM],[6 PM],[10 PM])) as datapivot
```

[image]

But I need the bellow Resultant table.

[image: image2]

Comment: an SQLfiddle with data would be suitable for that kind of question.

Comment: That exact table can`t exist in sqlserver since it is not a table.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have that table. The best you can do is create this columns instead and add the aditional header in the UI.

```
 07/11/2016 02:00 am
 07/11/2016 06:00 am
 07/11/2016 10:00 am
 07/11/2016 02:00 pm
 07/11/2016 06:00 pm
 07/11/2016 10:00 pm
 08/11/2016 02:00 am
 08/11/2016 06:00 am
 08/11/2016 10:00 am
 08/11/2016 02:00 pm
 08/11/2016 06:00 pm
 08/11/2016 10:00 pm
```

So change your query to

```
concat(convert(nvarchar(15),Date,103) Date,
       case Time 
             when '0' then '2' 
             when '1' then '6' 
             when '2' then '10' 
       end,' ',
       case AMPM 
             when '0' then 'AM' 
             when '1' then 'PM' 
       end) as [Tim]
```

and use a single pivot

```
pivot(max(Tim) for [Tim] in ([07/11/2016 02 AM],
                             [07/11/2016 06 AM],
                             [07/11/2016 10 AM],
                             [07/11/2016 02 PM],
                             [07/11/2016 06 PM],
                             [07/11/2016 10 PM]) .....) as datapivot
```

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with this that are unrelated to the question. So without affecting your original way of thinking too much:

```
DECLARE @HMS_Chart_Clinical TABLE (
 [ID]     INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
 [Temp]   INT, --0,1,2,3,4
 [Value]  INT,
 [Date]   DATE,
 [Time]   INT,   -- 0,1,2
 [AMPM]   INT,   -- 0,1
 [status] BIT,
 [IPNO]   INT
)

INSERT @HMS_Chart_Clinical ([Temp], [Value], [Date], [Time], [AMPM], [status], [IPNO]) VALUES (3, 125, '20161107', 2, 0, 0, 21460)
INSERT @HMS_Chart_Clinical ([Temp], [Value], [Date], [Time], [AMPM], [status], [IPNO]) VALUES (1, 26, '20161108', 2, 1, 0, 21460)
INSERT @HMS_Chart_Clinical ([Temp], [Value], [Date], [Time], [AMPM], [status], [IPNO]) VALUES (1, 99, '20161107', 1, 1, 0, 21460)
INSERT @HMS_Chart_Clinical ([Temp], [Value], [Date], [Time], [AMPM], [status], [IPNO]) VALUES (0, 106, '20161107', 0, 0, 0, 21460)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PivotSource') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PivotSource

  CREATE TABLE #PivotSource
  (
   Temp       VARCHAR(MAX),
   Value      INT,
   [DateTime] VARCHAR(MAX)
  )
  INSERT INTO #PivotSource
  SELECT CASE Temp 
           WHEN '0' THEN 'Temperature' 
           WHEN '1' THEN 'PULSE RATE/MIN'
           WHEN '2' THEN 'RESPIRATION/MIN' 
           WHEN '3' THEN 'BLOOD PRESSURE' 
           WHEN '4' THEN 'URINE' 
         END AS Temp,
         Value, 
         CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15),[Date],103) + ' ' + 
         CASE [Time] 
           WHEN '0' THEN '2' 
           WHEN '1' THEN '6' 
           WHEN '2' THEN '10' 
         END + ' ' + 
         CASE AMPM 
            WHEN '0' THEN 'AM' 
            WHEN '1' THEN 'PM' 
         END AS [DateTime]
    FROM @HMS_Chart_Clinical
   WHERE [status] = '0' 
     AND IPNO='21460' 

DECLARE @PivotColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH AllDatesAndTimes AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Date], 
           TimeString.[Time],
           TimeString.[SortOrder]
      FROM @HMS_Chart_Clinical
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '2 AM'  AS [Time], 0 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL SELECT '6 AM'  AS [Time], 1 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL SELECT '10 AM' AS [Time], 2 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL SELECT '2 PM'  AS [Time], 3 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL SELECT '6 PM'  AS [Time], 4 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL SELECT '10 PM' AS [Time], 5 AS SortOrder) TimeString
)  
SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + '], [', '') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15),[Date],103) + ' ' + [Time]
FROM AllDatesAndTimes
ORDER BY [Date],[SortOrder]

DECLARE @PivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'SELECT * FROM #PivotSource  PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR [DateTime] IN ([' + @PivotColumns + '])) AS DATAPIVOT'
EXEC(@PivotQuery)
```